# SMTP Exchange online Oauth implementation - Client Credential flow

Tags: exchange-online

We are currently using Basic authentication in exchange online for SMTP and want to move to Oauth protocol.
We want to use the client credentials grant flow to achieve the same.
I read the following document:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth

in which there is a section for:
Use client credentials grant flow to authenticate SMTP, IMAP, and POP connections   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth#use-client-credentials-grant-flow-to-authenticate-smtp-imap-and-pop-connections

However,
In the document above it says *This documentation uses the deprecated Outlook REST API scope. New applications should use the Graph REST API Endpoint instead.*

I couldn't find a way to use Graph REST API Endpoint to achieve the same. On Azure portal after selecting the application, API permissions > Add a permission > Microsoft Graph > Here under Delegated permission i could find "SMTP.Send" but for this i will have to log in the user, which is not my case. I want to use Client credentials grant flow and i couldnt find anything related to SMTP in API permissions > Add a permission > Microsoft Graph > Application permissions.

Am i missing something here?
Please do help!!

........................................